# Move Two characters from beginning to end of string

Tags: excel

I have an Excel 2010 document which has hundreds of rows each with a cell as below: 
(without the quotes, of course)

"XX - A Name of Something Here"

Which I need to change to:

"A Name of Something Here (XX)"

I'm trying to figure out the best way to accomplish this and could really use some assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`=RIGHT(A3, LEN(A3) - 5) & " (" & LEFT(A3, 2) & ")"`

which means

- all but the last 5 chars of the string, counting from right to left

  - 5 because XX space dash space is 5 chars long
- a space and an open parenthesis
- the leftmost two chars ie XX
- a close parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

This formula will work given your example

`=MID(A1&" ("&A1,5,LEN(A1))&")"`

Answer (score 0):

=RIGHT(A1, LEN(A1) - 5) & " (" &LEFT(A1, 2)  & ")"

Comment: your left and right functions are back to front.  That will produce "XX (A name of something here)".

Comment: @ZingZoingo Thanks. I reversed the statements to produce the correct output.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

**=MID(A1,3,9999) & "(" & LEFT(A1,2) & ")"**

but how about the dash??

Answer (score 0):

This will work too - I like "concatenate" since I don't need to keep track of the &'s

=CONCATENATE(RIGHT(A3,LEN(A3)-5)," (", LEFT(A3,2),")")

So many fun ways to do the same thing...