# little endian function in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, binary, decimal

I understood excel doesn't support little endian function. I have a binary number where I need to move the 8th bit to the beginning. example:
Target: 11001011
Result:
11100101

I've found this post:
[Move Two characters from beginning to end of string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19528928/move-two-characters-from-beginning-to-end-of-string)
but it didn't helped me with the binary number. what is the right formula?

and adding another question on top of it. I have the following binary number:
111001011011
why the formula BIN2DEC gives me an error? when I'm googling it, I'm getting the expected result:
https://www.binary-code.org/binary/12bit/111001011011/

Comment: It looks to me like it's one of each.

Comment: There is no duplicates

Comment: With 7 observations you have nowhere near enough data to empirically assess the distribution.  Sample sizes required to do decent distribution fitting are in the thousands or tens of thousands.  Instead, make an informed guess based on what's plausible given the source of the data.

Comment: I replaced the question with another...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For first question:
=RIGHT(AA3,1)&LEFT(AA3, LEN(AA3)-1 )

For second question:
=SUM((2^(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(X5)))-1))*MID(X5,LEN(X5)-ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&(LEN(X5))))+1,1))